# I need to save the text of a RichtTextBox before close the application

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a WinForm application and I need to save the text in a RichtTexBox before close the program because is a log.
I implemented that on Form1.Closing but sometimes I get an error because the RichtTexBox no longer exist.

The RichTextBox have a Delegate to add text.

Usually I get this error when I try to add text to the RichTextBox and the form is closing.

Can somebody tell some hints to have in account to avoid this situation?

Comment: Could you show us your code? There shouldn't be any problems saving it in the `FormClosing` event because that is raised _**before**_ the form starts closing and disposing of its controls. Thereby it is also possible to stop the form from closing by setting `e.Cancel = True`.

Comment: It seems like its a thread trying to access the control through the delegate after Form1.Closing event; is trying to write "The thread was being aborted". I need to recheck and debug the code. Thanks

Comment: You should never touch gui controls from a separate thread.

Comment: @LarsTech : If he's using `Control.Invoke()` correctly in order to access the `RichTextBox` then it should be fine.

Comment: @VisualVincent My confidence is low.  :-)

Comment: As I stated, the RichTextBox have a Delegate to add text; I did not access the control directly.

Comment: You're making this harder by not sharing your code.  Your other thread is trying to access the RichTextBox control after it's been disposed.  Don't let it do that.

Comment: @LarsTech It's about five thousand lines of code, you are going to get bored of read all the code.

Comment: We only need the code that duplicates the issue.

Comment: Maybe you would be better to save the log file every time it changes, by embedding you "save" code into the RichTextBox.TextChanged event? Or periodically save the contents using a timer?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim w, wz As IO.StreamWriter
w = New IO.StreamWriter(chl.Text & ("\listfulename-" & cmb_FileTypes.SelectedItem.ToString.Trim(".", "*") & "-.txt"))
wz = New IO.StreamWriter(chl.Text & ("\listnames-" & cmb_FileTypes.SelectedItem.ToString.Trim(".", "*") & "-.txt"))
For i = 0 To List.Items.Count - 1
  w.WriteLine(List.Items.Item(i))
  wz.WriteLine(ListBox1.Items.Item(i))
Next
w.Close()
wz.Close()
```

Comment: Despite the title, the question is about an exception.  Use four spaces to indent your code examples.  The OP is not using a ListBox either.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Dumping code in an answer without explaining it or at least the cause of the OP's problem is usually discouraged. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and also the [Formatting and Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

As Visual Vincent has said in his comment, reading the value of the RichTextBox in Form.Closing should not be an issue because it is raised before the controls are being disposed. Your exception is most likely due to your other thread trying to access the RichTextBox after it has been disposed.

Why don't you add a check in your delegate (or whatever method you use to access the control from the other thread) to see if the RichTextBox is null? If it is, then don't access it.
**Edit:** You'd want to take steps to make sure that the RichTextBox cannot be disposed of *after* you check for null but *before* you've accessed it, using a thread synchronization device such as a mutex.

Alternatively, if you want all the messages to be captured including the last one as the form is closing, you could wait till all your threads have exited in Form.Closing.